# Android XML layout_below doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place textview under the search bar. I used layout_below, but the text is not shown.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_margin"
        android:id="@+id/map_floating_search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"
        app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search for a room..."
        app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="false"
        app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_margin"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map_floating_search_view"
        android:hint="To" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/directions_go_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_margin"
        android:text="GO!" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_routing_criteria"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/avoid_indoor_pathways"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want edit_text_destination to be under FloatingSearchView. I am not sure why it doesn't work. If I replace FloatingSearchView by another textview, it works. I am struggling on it for a while. Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the way it's been implemented in the sample of the library? Take some idea from there. Maybe that will help you out.

Comment: `FloatingSearchView` inflates [`floating_search_layout.xml`](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/a0f8fbc90d98eb1b629c6295dd2d3577412e7b1e/library/src/main/res/layout/floating_search_layout.xml), which has `match_parent/match_parent` height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **static height** in `com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView`
as its search box takes whole height of screen for its results due to which the `edit_text` you are using gets shifted below and gets out of screen.. you can check this by applying `scrollView`, so try to give the height like 100dp or 200dp. 
**OR** 
if you want to disable the editText on click of searchBar and don't want to give static height then you can also use this.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_destination"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
            android:hint="To"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/directions_go_button"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/directions_go_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkbox_routing_criteria"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkbox_routing_criteria" />
```